# Mini DB - Dynamically update excel file from HTML form button - JavaScript/HTML/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on a HTML form. After I have selected from a drop-down option I click the 'Ok' (Button)

I want that 'onClick' action to dynamically updates a file on my desktop that adds a new line with some text from what I selected. Think a mini DB that gets updated with a new line of text each time I select something and click the button. Is this possible to update say a .txt file or a excel doc.

**HTML**

```
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Ok</button>
```

**File location**

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\book1.xlxs
```

OR

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\book1.csv
```

OR

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\book1.txt
```

Comment: You can't do that. Browsers don't allow Javascript to access the local file system for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Okay, how could one go about doing it, would I need a DB with auth? :(

Comment: Not necessarily. Modern browsers offer an onboard mini-DB called [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using pure javascript as it doesn't have access to the filesystem. Otherwise it would be a huge security breach.

You need to redirect your form content to a back-end application and use file manipulation methods accordingly.

Comment: As I said, Not necessarily. Modern browsers offer an onboard mini-DB called IndexedDB.